# Phonegap - Js function run only once

Tags: javascript, cordova

I try to make a phonegap build of my html / css / js game, in firefox there is no problem, but with a phonegap build (on my phone) there is a problem, a function (shuffle) run only one time (shuffle(arrays) run, but not shuffle (tree1), shuffle(tree2), ...) .

Thanks a lot

Comment: First things first, you should not be fetching JQuery, fonts etc from the network into your PhoneGap app.  Please make these local resources in your project's www/<wherever you want to put them> folder and update the links to them in your index.html.  Additionally don't start running your application logic until the "deviceready" event has fired.

Comment: remove `onload="onDeviceReady()"` attribute on the body element. **Note:** You will have to put that back in when you are debugging in the browser.

Comment: thanks for your answers, @ Simon Prickett, so where i do start running my application logic ?